# Elasticsearch - nested aggregation by weekday and hour

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

In our index (AWS Elasticsearch, 7.1) I have documents with the following simplified structure:

```
{
  "weekday" : {
     "type" : "long"
   },
  "start_datetime" : {
     "type" : "date",
     "format" : "yyyy/MM/dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
  },
  "count" : {
    "type" : "long"
   }
}
```

For an analysis, I want to have an aggregation first by weekday, then by hour, and finally summing up the count field for all documents in the final bucket. I have tried the following:

```
 "aggs": {
    "WEEKDAY": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "weekday"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "HOUR": {
         "date_histogram": {
            "field": "start_datetime",
            "interval": "hour", 
            "format": "HH:mm:ss"
         },
         "aggs": {
          "SUM": {
            "sum": {
              "field": "count"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Elasticsearch returns 7 WEEKDAY buckets and works fine if a run it on a datetime range of one week (no duplicated weekdays). When running on a timeframe of more than 7 days (e.g. a month) it returns also 7 WEEKDAY buckets but those not only contain the hours for the specific documents of this weekday but all other weekdays too. Any suggestions?

Comment: you can index new fields such as "day-of-week" , "hour-of-day" and use that field for the time-wheel aggregation.or you can read the doc here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html#_using_a_script_to_aggregate_by_day_of_the_week

Comment: I am not sure I understand what do you want to achieve. If there are two Mondays in your range, do you want one bucket with sum for both Mondays, or two different buckets? Or the problem is that in case when there is more than 7 days, in the Monday bucket there is a sum of Monday and, say, Tuesday? I am a little confused, may you provide an example with data?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by using painless scripting. In case someone need the solution for his/her project:

```
"aggs": {
   "WEEKDAY": {
      "terms": {
         "field": "weekday",
         "order" : { "_key" : "asc" }
      },
      "aggs": {
         "HOUR": {
            "histogram": {
               "script": "doc['start_datetime'].value.getHourOfDay()",
               "interval": 1,
               "min_doc_count": 0,
               "extended_bounds": {
                  "min": 0,
                  "max": 23
                },
                "order": {
                    "_key": "asc"
                }
              },
             "aggs": {
                "SUM": {
                  "sum": {
                     "field": "count"
                   }
                 }
               }
             }
           }
         }
       }
```